# Conditional expectation on partition

Tags: probability, probability-theory

Consider $X\in L^2(\Omega,\mathcal{A},P)$ with $\Omega = A_1 \cup A_2$, $A_1 \cap A_2 = \emptyset$, $P(A_i)>0$ and $\mathcal{F}=\sigma(A_1,A_2)$. How do I compute $E[X^2|\mathcal{F}]$?

I know that $E[X|\mathcal{F}]=\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{A_1}]}{P(A_1)}\mathbb{1}_{A_1}+\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{A_2}]}{P(A_2)}\mathbb{1}_{A_2}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we know $E[X|\mathcal{F}]=\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{A_1}]}{P(A_1)}\mathbb{1}_{A_1}+\frac{E[X\mathbb{1}_{A_2}]}{P(A_2)}\mathbb{1}_{A_2}$ by definition, then

$E[X^2|\mathcal{F}]=\frac{E[X^2\mathbb{1}_{A_1}]}{P(A_1)}\mathbb{1}_{A_1}+\frac{E[X^2\mathbb{1}_{A_2}]}{P(A_2)}\mathbb{1}_{A_2}$.